# Ensuring that object exists at delayed call from block

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, grand-central-dispatch

In the code pasted below, how can I check/ensure that the object still exists when the call to 'showResultToUser' is performed and that I won't get a call to an already released object?

```
__block MyClass pSelf = self;

dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^
{
    [pSelf doSomeBackgroundWork];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [pSelf showResultToUser];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you are using `__block` and not `__weak`? You don't appear to be changing the value of `self` (which would be an odd thing to do anyway) and using a weak reference would both prevent any retain cycle and ensure that if the `pSelf` object was released, your variable would point to `nil` and you wouldn't risk a bad access crash.

Comment: I am not using ARC on this project (yet) so as far as I understand __weak does not do anything here

Answer (score 0):

From the apple developer website:

> __block variables live in storage that is shared between the lexical scope of the variable and all blocks and block copies declared or created within the variable’s lexical scope. Thus, the storage will survive the destruction of the stack frame if any copies of the blocks declared within the frame survive beyond the end of the frame (for example, by being enqueued somewhere for later execution). Multiple blocks in a given lexical scope can simultaneously use a shared variable.

This means that it will not have been released.

---

Other than that there is no way to check if a handle you have references a valid variable, since if it *was* released it could have been re-used by another valid (but different) variable, which your 'test' would say was OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is getting confused by the __block allocation behavior and whether the pSelf variable is itself in stable storage (which it is:  __block causes it to get allocated on the heap even if it's declared inside a stack frame).  What's more important, in the absence of ARC (which you say you're not using), is that you explicitly retain such objects before passing the block to dispatch_async() and then release them from within the block.  See the man page for dispatch_async and look for a section labeled "COMPLETION CALLBACKS" where a async_read() function is being created as an example - see how the destination queue is being retained and then released?  Following the same pattern will keep you out of trouble.

Note that ObjC instance variable objects inside of blocks automatically get retention behavior "for free" (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) but there's also no harm in being explicit in your retain/release behavior since it makes the code clearer (IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent the object from being deallocated by removing the `__block` qualified variable:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(queue, ^
{
    [self doSomeBackgroundWork];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^
    {
        [self showResultToUser];
    });
});
```

You might unnecessarily extend the lifetime of the referenced object, but it will be deallocated at the end of the inner block's execution if nothing else retains it.